# Connect with modbus device every 10 seconds

Tags: java, modbus

I am working on modbus device which is connected with system through serial port. I can read/write data on device's register. I am using java for data read/write.

The device automatically turns off on every 10 seconds, to keep it activated I need to establish the connection on every 10 seconds. How can I achieve this requirement?

[image: Device's Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use timer class to establish connection every 10 seconds as such:

```
class EstablishConnection extends TimerTask {
   public void run() {
      // Code to establish connection 
   }
}
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new EstablishConnection(), 0, 10000);
```